How to run local "solc" instead of global "solc" for local project?
I have installed solc@0.8.26 globally, but a recent project needs to use solc@0.8.20. I have installed solc@0.8.20 in the local project folder (/node_modules/.bin/solcjs). But when I try "solc --version" in local project folder, I still get "Version: 0.8.26+commit.8a97fa7a.Linux.g++".
How can I make sure that in the project folder, whenever I run "solc", it will be using the version installed locally?
Thank you for your time.
